# Site too Slow to establish db connection?

Tags: performance

After deployment site was too slow on analysis it takes time at db connection side.
DB is in remote server.
Trying queries without WordPress gives faster response. 
But WordPress takes around 40 sec waiting for DB ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has something to do with your database server to speed up response time. Also may be it is validating your IP from where your are pinging . If you can whitelist your IP,the connection would be more reliable and may increase ping time.

Comment: Thanks .DBA just reset and added db permissions and my issue got fixed